How to unmarshall JSON when the fields can have different types depending on other fields?
Assume I have a JSON message that looks like this:
{
    "type": string
    "data": list of something that is based on above type
}

two examples might be
{
    "type": "car"
    "data": [{"color": "red", "mpg": 16.4}]
}

and
{
    "type": "house"
    "data": [{"color": "blue", "state": "CA"}]
}

I want to define a struct so I can basically only decode the type and then use that to properly unmarshal the data field. I tried the following
type message struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Data []byte `json:"data"`
}

type car struct {
    Color string
    MPG   float64
}

type house struct {
    Color string
    State string
}

erroneously thinking that it would just leave the Data field raw for me to unmarshal later into either the car or house struct. I know I can define Data as a []interface{} and do some other work to get what I want, but I was wondering if this is (currently) the best way in Go? In case it comes up, assume I cannot change the JSON definitions - I'm just the consumer of a service here.

This is a perfect use-case for json.RawMessage. Check out the Unmarshal example there.
For your example, this would look something like:
type message struct {
    Type string            `json:"type"`
    Data []json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

type car struct {
    Color string
    MPG   float64
}

type house struct {
    Color string
    State string
}

func main() {
    if err := parseAndPrint(carJSON); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := parseAndPrint(houseJSON); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func parseAndPrint(b []byte) error {
    msg := new(message)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, msg); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    switch msg.Type {
    case "car":
        for _, data := range msg.Data {
            c := new(car)
            if err := json.Unmarshal(data, c); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            fmt.Println(c)
        }
    case "house":
        for _, data := range msg.Data {
            h := new(house)
            if err := json.Unmarshal(data, h); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            fmt.Println(h)
        }
    }
    return nil
}


// Tucked here to get out of the way of the example
var carJSON = []byte(`
{
    "type": "car",
    "data": [{"color": "red", "mpg": 16.4}]
}
`)

var houseJSON = []byte(`{
    "type": "house",
    "data": [{"color": "blue", "state": "CA"}]
}
`)

Now what you do with the parsed result is kinda up to you and your program's needs. Parse at the edge and only pass down the fully-typed message, add a Parsed any field to the outer struct, etc.

Wow - I've been messing with this for a few days and searching all over SO and other sites. First I've ever heard of this - thanks so much for sharing!

type message struct {
    Type string
    Data any
}

func (m *message) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var obj struct {
        Type string          `json:"type"`
        Data json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var val any
    var err error
    switch obj.Type {
    case "car":
        val, err = decodeArrayOf[car](obj.Data)

    case "house":
        val, err = decodeArrayOf[house](obj.Data)
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    m.Type = obj.Type
    m.Data = val
    return nil
}

func decodeArrayOf[T any](data []byte) ([]*T, error) {
    v := []*T{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return v, nil
}

https://go.dev/play/p/LxzBr5I68fc
